# Rearranging equation with Sums

Tags: optimization, summation

Could anyone help me with rearranging the below to find $\mu$:

$$\sum^{N-1}_{n = 0}\frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}(x_n - \mu) = 0$$

The mark scheme for the question seems to rearrange the equation like this:
$$\sum_n\frac{x_n}{\sigma_n^2} = \mu\sum_n\sum_n\frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}$$

However, I have no clue why there is two sums on the right hand side, and why it doesn't just rearrange to $ \sum_n\frac{x_n}{\sigma_n^2} = \mu\sum_n\frac{1}{\sigma_n^2} $.
Thanks to anyone that can help me out.

Comment: It's a typo, there should only be one sum.

Comment: Is $x_n$ a random variable or an observation? I suspect that the first equality is true.

Comment: @callculus42 $x_n$ is an observation

Comment: If it is an observation you cannot guarantee that the sum is equal to $\mu$ or any other specific value. And if $x_n$ is an observation what then is $\sigma_n$, the standard deviation of $x_n$? It woud be helpful if you would add some context.

Comment: @callculus42 The original question is a maximum likelihood question. Some data, $x_n$, is modelled as $x_n = \mu + e_n$. $\mu$ is an unknown paramater, and $e_n$ is gaussian white noise with zero mean and variance $\sigma_n^2$, and the variance is known but different for each value of n. The question asks to find the maximum likelihood estimator for the unknown parameter $\mu$, and when optimising the equation, I arrive at the formula shown in the original post, which is correct. The part I'm stuck on is re arranging to find the required $\mu$ in the equation, as this value will be optimal.

Comment: angryavian is correct. It is only a typo. Someone probably inserted the summation with a copy-paste operation and accidently pasted twice. And evidently they also didn't proof-read afterwards. This is clear, as the sum obviously *does* rearrange into your form, and the right-hand-side of their form simplifies to $N\mu \sum_n \frac1{\sigma_n^2}$, where $N$ is the total number of observations, and this is not the same. ($n$ is a dummy variable for the inner sum. The result of that sum no longer depends on a variable $n$. Thus the outer sum is just $N$ copies of the same value added together.)